# django: issue with javascript redirection after form submission and download

Tags: javascript, python, django

I need to redirect a user after he finishes filling up a form and clicking on download, which generate a pdf template and then downloads it.

I have tried redirecting from the backend side in django as well as in client side with javascript and nothing makes it.

here is what I currently have:

1. USER INPUT VIEW

```
def New_Sales(request):
    #context = {}
    form = modelformset_factory(historical_recent_data, fields=('id','Id', 'Description','Date','Quantity', 'NetAmount', 'customer_name', 'invoice_number'))
     
    
    if request.method == 'GET':
        formset = form(queryset= historical_recent_data.objects.none())
        
        #blank_form = formset.empty_form
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        formset = form(request.POST)
        #invoice_hidden_form = CreateInvoiceForm(request.POST)
        
        #blank_form = formset.empty_form
        if formset.is_valid():
            #request.session['sale'] = formset.cleaned_data
            
            for check_form in formset:
                check_form.save()
                quantity = check_form.cleaned_data.get('Quantity')
                id = check_form.cleaned_data.get('Id')
                update = replenishment.objects.filter(Id = id).update(StockOnHand = F('StockOnHand') - quantity)
                update2 = Item2.objects.filter(reference = id).update(stock_reel = F('stock_reel') - quantity)
                
            
            request.session['sale'] = formset.cleaned_data
            #if invoice_hidden_form.is_valid():
                #invoice_hidden_form.save()
                #print('invoice_hidden_form is saved successfully')
                #request.session['invoice'] = invoice_hidden_form.cleaned_data
            print(formset.cleaned_data)
        
            return redirect('/invoice/pdf/assembly/')
```

2. PDF GENERATION + DOWNLOAD VIEW:

```
def generate_pdf_assembly(request):
    data = request.session['sale']
    
    invoice_number = data[0]['invoice_number']
    print(data)
    #total_ht = request.session['sale'].get('NetAmount')
    rate_list = []
    for index in range(len(data)):
        rate_list.append(round(data[index]['NetAmount']/data[index]['Quantity'],1))
   
    total_ht = []
    for index in range(len(data)):
        total_ht.append(data[index]['NetAmount'])
        
    print('total_ht', total_ht)
    total_ht = sum(total_ht)
    my_company = MyCompany.objects.get(id = 1)
    
    tva = MyCompany.objects.aggregate(Sum('TVA'))['TVA__sum']
    tva_value = round(total_ht * tva,1)
    total_ttc = total_ht + tva_value
    tableau = zip(rate_list, data)
    
    context = {'data' : data, 
               'my_company' : my_company, 
               'total_ht':total_ht, 
               'tva_value':tva_value, 
               'total_ttc':total_ttc, 
               'rate_list':rate_list, 
               'tableau':tableau,
               'invoice_number':invoice_number,
               
            
             }
    print("context",context)
    
    pdf = render_to_pdf('pdf/invoice_generator_assembly.html', context)
    if pdf:
        response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
        filename = "Melt_Invoice_{}.pdf".format(data[0]['customer_name'])
        content = "inline; filename={}".format(filename)
        content = "attachment; filename={}".format(filename)
        response['Content-Disposition'] = content
        return response
    return HttpResponse("Not found")
```

here is the redirection code looks like in pdf/invoice_generator_assembly.html, I try redirecting as a success when the data has been acquired by AJAX

```
<script>
        
            $.ajax({
                method: "GET",
                url: "/new_sale.html", 
                sucess: function(context){
                    alert(context);
                    window.location = '/dash2.html';
                },
                failure: function(context){
                    alert('got an error');
                    
                }
            });

    </script>
```

But here is what gets outputed in Chrome dev tool

[image]

the redirection never occurs, send help pleaaase

Comment: this should be working the issue could be that one of your conditions in python is not working, are all the prints you made directing to the redirect working?

Comment: yes they all work, just to verify, the javascript code should inside of the  generate_pdf_assembly template, right?