# write a custom redirection decorator in django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to write a variation of the following redirection decorator:

```
def permanent_redirect(url):
  
  
    def outer(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def inner(request, *args, **kwargs):
            
            f(request, *args, **kwargs)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(url if not callable(url) else url())
        return inner
    return outer
```

my goal is to use it as such:

```
#@permanent_redirect('/dash2.html')
def generate_pdf_assembly(request):
    data = request.session['sale']
    invoice_number = data[0]['invoice_number']
    print("this is data from generate pdf assembly", data)
    #total_ht = request.session['sale'].get('NetAmount')
    rate_list = []
    for index in range(len(data)):
        rate_list.append(round(data[index]['NetAmount']/data[index]['Quantity'],1))
   
    total_ht = []
    for index in range(len(data)):
        total_ht.append(data[index]['NetAmount'])
        
    print('total_ht', total_ht)
    total_ht = sum(total_ht)
    my_company = MyCompany.objects.get(id = 1)
    
    tva = MyCompany.objects.aggregate(Sum('TVA'))['TVA__sum']
    tva_value = round(total_ht * tva,1)
    total_ttc = total_ht + tva_value
    tableau = zip(rate_list, data)
    
    context = {'data' : data, 
               'my_company' : my_company, 
               'total_ht':total_ht, 
               'tva_value':tva_value, 
               'total_ttc':total_ttc, 
               'rate_list':rate_list, 
               'tableau':tableau,
               'invoice_number':invoice_number,
               
            
             }
    print("context",context)
    
pdf = render_to_pdf(url, context)
    if pdf:
        response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
        print("response ok")
        filename = "Melt_Invoice_{}.pdf".format(data[0]['customer_name'])
        print("filename ok")
        
        content = "inline; filename={}".format(filename)
        print("content ok")
        content = "attachment; filename={}".format(filename)
        print("content 2 ok")
        response['Content-Disposition'] = content
        print("response ok")
        return response
    else:
        print("fuck this shit")
    return HttpResponse("Not found")
```

although this redirect just fine, the issue with it is that it ignores rendered values, or generared files on the view it is placed.

I am a bit of out of my game here honestly, how would I go about modifying this decorator so it takes what is outputed by the view into account?

UPDATE: I manage to write 2 versions of the decorator but I still struggle, one of them redirect fine and the other downloads the fine well but does not redirect

redirection and download decorator version1:
This one redirect the user without problem but does not download the file.

```
def download_and_redirect(url, view):
    def outer(f):
        @wraps(view)
        def inner(request, *args, **kwargs):
            def inner_inner(request, *args, **kwargs):
                data = request.session['sale']
                print(data)
                context = request.session['context']
                print(context)
                pdf = render_to_pdf('pdf/invoice_generator_assembly.html', context)
                if pdf:
                   response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
                   print("response ok")
                #filename = "Melt_Invoice_{}.pdf".format(data[0]['customer_name'])
                   filename = "Melt_Invoice_{}.pdf"
                   print("filename ok")
        
                   content = "inline; filename={}".format(filename)
                   print("content ok")
                   content = "attachment; filename={}".format(filename)
                   print("content 2 ok")
                   response['Content-Disposition'] = content
                   print("response ok")
                   return response
                else:
                   print("fuck this shit")
                return HttpResponse("Not found")
         
            f(request, *args, **kwargs)
            
            return HttpResponseRedirect(url if not callable(url) else url())
        return inner
    return outer
```

download and redirect decorator version2:
this one download the file well but cannot make the redirect:

```
def download_and_redirect(url, view):
    def outer(f):
        @wraps(view)
        def inner(request, *args, **kwargs):
            
                data = request.session['sale']
                print(data)
                context = request.session['context']
                print(context)
                pdf = render_to_pdf('pdf/invoice_generator_assembly.html', context)
                if pdf:
                   response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
                   print("response ok")
                #filename = "Melt_Invoice_{}.pdf".format(data[0]['customer_name'])
                   filename = "Melt_Invoice_{}.pdf"
                   print("filename ok")
        
                   content = "inline; filename={}".format(filename)
                   print("content ok")
                   content = "attachment; filename={}".format(filename)
                   print("content 2 ok")
                   response['Content-Disposition'] = content
                   print("response ok")
                   return response
                else:
                   print("fuck this shit")
                return HttpResponse("Not found")
         
                f(request, *args, **kwargs)
            
                return HttpResponseRedirect(url if not callable(url) else url())
        return inner
    return outer
```

Comment: what exactly do you want to do with the returned value?

Comment: let me update my post to better show you what I try to achieve. Basically, this current decorator prevent a file from being downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

#### Why doesn't it work?

Lets simplify your functions:

```
def generate_pdf_assembly(request):
    pdf = maybe_generate_a_pdf(request)
    if pdf:
        response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = get_content(request)
        return response
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Not found")
```

Notice there are no side-effects to this function, the generated pdf is returned via the return value. Now look at your decorator.

```
def permanent_redirect(url):
    def outer(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def inner(request, *args, **kwargs):    
            f(request, *args, **kwargs)         # This line is the problem
            return HttpResponseRedirect(url if not callable(url) else url())
        return inner
    return outer
```

Look what happens here `f(request, *args, **kwargs)`. That's where your view is being called, and the returned value isn't assigned to anything (you don't do `x = f(request, *args, **kwargs)`. So the HttpResponse with your pdf attachment goes nowhere, to be lost forever. You are then redirected accordingly.

#### How to fix it?

This isn't quite so straight forward. It depends what you want to do to be honest, but it looks like what you are trying to do is, download the file and then once the file has been downloaded redirect the user to a new page.

If this is the case, then it's not something you can achieve on the backend, and you will need to do some clever javascript to handle this. It would be better to ask a separate question that addresses that specifically as it is beyond the scope of what this question is about.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am a beginner to django and really banging my head off the wall with this issue, check this out, I have already  attempted this afternoon with javascript without success either : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64687103/django-issue-with-redirection-after-form-submission-and-download